# Drawing Letters in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, paint

I am trying to design an application that teaches how to write the letters.

I thought that I can show how a letter is written by moving a point across the screen, but I need some help in directing me to a good way for doing it.

I want to be able to keep the previous points on screen and have some delay between showing different points. In other words, I want to be able to trace the path that a point moves across.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you draw a letter on the screen, copy each MotionEvents and stack it.
You can catch many touch data.(coordinates, time, event-type, etc...)

```
private ArrayList<MotionEvent> mLetterTouchStack;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
{
    mLetterTouchStack.add(MotionEvent.obtain(evt));
    return super.onTouchEvent(eat);
}
```

Comment: I don't want the user to write the letters, it is the application that does that.

Comment: @H.K I mean you draw every letters before publishing, and store it in app(with files, static final variables, etc...).

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to look like the app is writing hte letter as a model for the user to follow, to see what writing that letter would look like?